# Install WSGI in my apache localhost Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, linux, apache, wsgi

I'm using LAMP server in my Ubuntu 12.04. and want to install wsgi module in apache for running python application. How install this module ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
# sudo apt-get install apache2 apache2.2-common apache2-mpm-prefork apache2-utils libexpat1 ssl-cert

# sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi

# sudo service apache2 restart
```

After you succeed all that, go to your apache httpd conf enable WSGI module configure your pythone app and restart apache again.